# Django - Login required redirect url

Tags: django

If the user is not logged-in, I want it to redirect to the admin page and when the user logs in, he should be redirected to the previous url.

This is how I'm doing:-

```
LOGIN_URL = '/admin'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/admin'
```

The user does get redirected to `admin` page but after logging in, the admin dashboard is open, not the next url. That's because the url is not exactly what django is expecting.

This is how the url looks like.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/%3Fnext%3D/movies/fav%253Fpage%253D1
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What does it mean? Didnt get you.

Comment: Done. `LOGIN_URL = '/admin/login/'` This worked.

Answer (score 1):

Tried this. And it worked.

```
LOGIN_URL = '/admin/login/'
```